# How does java.util.prefs.Preferences work in Java?

Tags: java, preferences, flush

I've recently faced to *flush()* method documentation and it said:

> Forces any changes in the contents of this preference node and its descendants to the persistent store.

Aren't the changes are made immediately in Preferences? I mean the methods:

- `preferences.node(String name)`- node creation
- `preferences.put(String key, String value)` - key-value adding to node
- `Preferences.importPreferences(InputStream is)` - preferences import from stream (eg. file stream)

Java sources and docks are not clear for me. Can someone explain me when I need to call `preferences.flush()` and what happen if i wouldn't do that?

Answer (score 1):

The preferences are saved when you call put method. However for high performance reason sometimes the API look for the best time to write the bytes.

You can have a lot of put method calls. In this case probable the API write to the store at the end of all put method. If you want that the write will be made just after the put mehtod call you use the flush method.